# How can I add an object with a material with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I'm now onto coding my second blender addon but I need help. My idea is inspired by [this](https://github.com/TheDuckCow/MCprep/releases) addon. I would like to know how to make it that when the user presses add a cube button in the panel all the have to do is press z to go into material mode and the material will be displayed like how in mcprep when you add an item or mob all you have to do is press z and got material and it shows the material.

```
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name" : "Minecraft for blender",
    "author" : "Master1015",
    "description" : "An addon to help you to render and create minecraft animations",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "location" : "View3D Toolbar > Minecraft Addon",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Add Mesh"
}
 
   #This is the Main Panel 
class MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Minecraft addon "
    bl_idname = "PT_MainPanel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Minecraft addon'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.scale_y = 1.2
   
    #Operation to add basic meshes in blender 
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text= "Add Minecraft Block", icon= 'OBJECT_ORIGIN')
        row = layout.row()       
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cube_add", icon='MATCUBE', text="Cube")

    #Here we are Registering the Classes       
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MainPanel)
       
    #Here we are UnRegistering the Classes   
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MainPanel)
      
    #This is required in order for the script to run in the text editor   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

So as you can see my addon works because it appears in the blender UI which is where I want it to. So I now what I need help to do is I want it so that when I press add cube I want it so that when you switch to material mode it comes out as the cube on left hand side.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your first link is broken. Please add a descriptive title that reflects the content of your question. Also post any relevant code of your second addon showing what you already have so it is easier to help you

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the broken link I have now fixed it. I have added a full stop at the end of the link by mistake.

Comment: Both of    "How to add an object", and "how to add a material" have been covered extensively.  IMO would look at the add new mesh text editor python template which is an example of writing an operator to create a simple object.  Extend it with material adding code. Currently your "addon" simply places a button for default add cube operator to a panel.  _ie_ instead use your own operator. All addon code is readily available to peruse.

Comment: Thanks for helping